# Updating chart after checkbox change in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Good evening,

I'm new to JavaScript and would really appreciate your help.
I'm trying to update circle stats depending on the status of a checkbox (checked or unchecked). If the checkbox is checked the circle stat is created with a value of 40%. If not, then its value is 100%. Everything works fine when I load the page but the circle stats won't update when I check/uncheck the checkbox.

Here is my code:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

    if ($('#checkHFX').is(':checked') == true) //This works
        {       
            $('.my-stat').cirque ({
            value: 40,
            total: 100,
            arcColor: '#FF9900',    
            label: 'percent',
            });
        }
        else    
        {
            $('.my-stat').cirque ({
            value: 100,
            total: 100,
            arcColor: '#FF9900',    
            label: 'percent',
            });
        }

    $('#checkHFX').change(function(){       
        if ($('#checkHFX').is(':checked') == true)
        {       
            alert("checked"); //Only the alert works 
            $('.my-stat').cirque ({
            value: 40,
            total: 100,
            arcColor: '#FF9900',    
            label: 'percent',
            });
        }
        else    
        {
            alert("unchecked");  //Only the alert works     
            $('.my-stat').cirque ({
            value: 100,
            total: 100,
            arcColor: '#FF9900',    
            label: 'percent',
            });
        }       
    }); 
}); 
</script>
```

And the HTML code
    ......

```
<div>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkHFX" name="checkHFX" value="1">HFX<br>
</div>

<div class="my-stat"></div>
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Kind regards,

Olivia

Comment: Hi, did you manage do do this ? I'm need this functionality as well....

Answer (score 0):

The logic could be more concise, but looks sound. Are you sure .cirque() supports being called again to update the value?

What library is the .cirque() method a part of?

Comment: The Cirque function is defined in a js file cirque.js. How can I figure out if it supports being called many times?